# my uwp app is reported to crash on launch

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

I submit my app to the Microsoft Store but Microsoft Store Team reports my app to crash on launch. However, when I build my app in either Debug mode or Release mode, it runs perfectly.

Actually my first submission was also reported to crash on launch, and I received help saying that my minimum supported version needs upgrading. I changed it and my submission was then successful.

However, in the later submissions I fixed some bugs in my code and I didn't add any functionalities from newer version of Windows, my submissions are reported to crash again. I couldn't figure out why.

Since I write my project simply for fun, I don't want to create a virtual environment to torture myself. I think there should be a more manageable reason for the crash.

One thing that I think might be helpful is, one of the package that I use, `TagLib` is reported that it is not fully compatible with my app (as it uses NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 instead of the project target framework UAP,Version=v10.0.17763). But that package is not used on launch.

This is my [project link](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer).

--- Update ---

This is the report that I got from Microsoft:

> App Policies: 10.4.2 Usability
>
> Notes To Developer
>
> Unfortunately, we can’t test the app, because the app crashes at
>   launch.
>
> Tip: A Windows app may run flawlessly during development and testing,
>   but after submitting it for certification testing, the app may crash
>   or perform unexpectedly. Along these same lines, your app may not
>   perform as expected after publication. You can contact Developer
>   Support at http://aka.ms/storesupport if you need assistance with
>   troubleshooting.
>
> Tested Devices: Dell Inspiron 12-5280, Lenovo MIIX 520

Comment: First of all - very nice app! I have tried it locally, but I don't observe any launch issues. Could you copy the full report you received from Microsoft Store team, is there any additional information? You could also add App Center support to your application as they now have full UWP crash reporting, so hopefully, when the crash occurs at Microsoft, you could potentially get the crash report in App Center.

Comment: @MartinZikmund Thank you. Actually adding App Center Support makes my app crash in the release mode, while in the debug mode it is okay...So I removed it. I have attached their report in the updated question.

Comment: Have you tested on a machine without Visual Studio installed?

I would ask the Store support for a crash dump. Not sure why they aren't already providing this by default when they reject due to crash ...

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT No because I only have one Windows machine...By the way how do you test the app without vs? The packaging gives me the `SMPlayer_1.1.0.0_x86_x64_arm_bundle.msixupload` file, which cannot be simply run, right?

Comment: Starts here well without any problem. Windows version 1903.19013.1000.

Comment: @Weissu Thank you 1903 is actually also my Windows version.

Comment: You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit) to use WACK to test your app or create a virtual machine of the same system version to test.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I am using the same operating system as the test team.

Comment: When we install Visual Studio, it will install some SDKs and dependencies for computer. These dependencies may miss on the target device and then cause applications that use these dependencies to crash. We should create a clean environment for normal users to test, which is why we advise you to use a virtual machine. And you can also put the installed package on other devices to test.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT So if normal users don't have those dependencies, how should I fix it?

Comment: Missing dependencies is one possibility, you should try to install the application in the virtual machine and reproduce the problem. In that case, it's easy to find what caused the problem.